# Number of serotonergic neurons in mouse/rat DRN

Tags: cell-biology, neurophysiology, serotonin

What is the (approximate) number of serotonergic neurons in the dorsal raphe nucleus (DRN) of mice and rats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **mouse** and **rat** dorsal raphe nuclei contain about 9000 and about 11.500 serotonergic neurons, respectively. It turns out the corresponding [1988](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3185964/) and [1982](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7107985) references are widely cited - directly as well as indirectly. I could not find any newer data/evaluations.